# Google sheets - Line Chart

Tags: google-sheets, charts, google-visualization, linechart, google-query-language

I am new to Google sheets and trying to create a timeline line chart. The data is as follows.

[image]

Col1 defines Project, Col2 defines the hours left for the projects, Col3 defines the start date and Col4 defines the End time of the Project.

I am trying to create a line chart where each line represents a Project with the value on y-axis as Hours left and on x Axis it shows Date. The line height (on y-axis) will be defined by Hours Left and the length of line (on x-axis) will be defined by start date and end date (as below).

[image]

I've tried different combinations, but not reaching a proper solution.

I can also try to change the formatting of data, if that is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line chart is based on series so you need to reorganize your data like this:

```
=QUERY(A2:D, "select D,max(B) where B is not null group by D pivot A")
```

[image]